# Função/Método para mudar uma variável a partir de outro arquivo em PHP?

Tags: php, html, funções

Tenho uma página de login que pega uma variável de outro arquivo, que no início está vazia, e coloca abaixo da tela de login. Se o usuário errar login/senha ou não inserir nada, a variável deve ser alterada para "Login Inválido" em uma segunda página que redirecionará de volta à tela de login, onde irá aparecer o texto em vermelho.

Tenho, no arquivo `index.php` (página de login):

```
<br/><p class='login-status'>
    <?php
        include "Controller/LoginStatus.php";
            echo $loginStatus;
    ?>
</p>
```

Quando o usuário clica no botão de login do form, as informações vão por post para o arquivo `Login.php`:

```
include "../Model/Usuario.php";

$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$data = array($tipo, $login, $senha);
$error = false;
foreach($data as $field) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
      $error = true;
    }
}

if ($error) {
    include "LoginStatus.php";
    setStatus("Login inválido.");
    header("Location: ../");
} else {
    $user = new Usuario();
    $retorno = $user->verificarLogin($tipo, $login, $senha);

    if($retorno){
        echo "Login efetuado. Redirecionando...";
        header("Location: ../View");
    } else{
        include "LoginStatus.php";
        header("Location: ../");
    }
}
```

E no arquivo `LoginStatus.php`:

```
$loginStatus = "";
function setStatus($input){
    $loginStatus = $input;
}
```

Porém, não está mudando a variável loginStatus. Queria saber qual o erro, ou se tem algum método mais direto/fácil de alterar ela a partir do Login.php. Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você que salvar o status se o usuário está logado ou não?

A melhor maneira é usar uma sessão para isso:

Você não precisaria mais do arquivo `LoginStatus.php`

em seu `index.php`

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<br/><p class='login-status'>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['loginStatus'])){
            echo $_SESSION['loginStatus'];
        }
    ?>
</p>
```

e o `Login.php`

```
session_start();
include "../Model/Usuario.php";

$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$data = array($tipo, $login, $senha);
$error = false;
foreach($data as $field) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
      $error = true;
    }
}

if ($error) {
    $_SESSION['loginStatus'] = "Os campos são obrigatórios.";
    header("Location: ../");
} else {
    $user = new Usuario();
    $retorno = $user->verificarLogin($tipo, $login, $senha);

    if($retorno){
        echo "Login efetuado. Redirecionando...";
        header("Location: ../View");
    } else{
        $_SESSION['loginStatus'] = "Login inválido.";
        header("Location: ../");
    }
}
```

Comment: Na verdade eu quero que, se o usuário errar o login ou deixar em branco, quando redirecionar de volta à página de login seja alterada a variável, mostrando "Login inválido" em baixo.

Comment: Isto mesmo q o script faz

Comment: Ok, funcionou. Muito obrigado :D